# Onenote API - Can page content include handwriting?

Tags: onenote

When I make a GET request for a page's content from Onenote API, the html does not include my handwriting.  Is there a way to include the handwriting?  What am I doing wrong?  Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately handwriting (aka 'ink') is currently not returned through the API. Follow us on twitter @OneNoteDev for future announcements about its availability.